# select records from db and insert into C++ map

Tags: c++

Can someone suggest me a good example or link to select records from MySQL and insert the records into a map so I can do the analysis in C++.
I am trying to pull in price data from the db, so I have a transaction date and sale price.
I don't want to go through the intermediate step and write the records to a .csv file.

thx!

---

i was not able to get it work with sql::Connection so I used the API. I am trying to extract date and sales$'s from the db, which has other fields also. so, here is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include </usr/include/mysql/mysql.h>
#include </usr/include/sys/time.h> 
using namespace std;

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>

MYSQL *connection;
MYSQL mysql;
MYSQL_RES *resptr;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_FIELD *field;

int query_state;

map<string, double> test;
string key;
double value;

int main() 
{
mysql_init(&mysql);
connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","userid","pwd","schema",0,0,0);

query_state = mysql_query(connection, "select pdate, sales from test;");

 resptr = mysql_store_result(connection); 


while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(resptr)) != NULL ) 
{

test[resptr->getString("pdate")]=resptr->getInt("sales"); 
} 

mysql_free_result(resptr);
mysql_close(connection);

return 0;
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
error: ‘struct MYSQL_RES’ has no member named ‘getString’

error: ‘struct MYSQL_RES’ has no member named ‘getInt’
```

Comment: It may be actually easier and more portable for C++ code to read .csv.

Comment: I was asked to do it this way, so no choice.  btw, I noticed on your profile you build electronic trading systems...I want to get into that business eventually...any suggestions on good reading to get started?

Comment: Hard to tell. You just need to be technically good, so things like sockets, multi-threading, messaging and basic statistics are useful.

Comment: I am good at statistics and want to learn about sockets and multi-threading....if you have any good website recommendation, do let me know. cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the C++ connector. You can download it from [this link](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/).

[Here's the wiki page to get you started](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp.html).

**Edit:** I haven't tested this myself, but something like this should work:

```
map<int, string> results;

sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
sql::Connection* con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");

sql::Statement* stmt = con->createStatement();
sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id, label FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");
while (res->next())
{
    results[res->getInt("id")] = res->getString("label");
}

delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
```

Comment: what's the difference between using sql::Connection *con; and 
MYSQL *connection; is one using the API and the other the connector. also, can you suggest an example that shows how to insert what is read from the db into a C++ map. thx!

Comment: MySQL_Driver exposes the interface to work with the database. sql::Connection represents a connection. I don't know the schema of your tables or what you're trying to do, but I added an example that imports data from a table to a map. Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't know how to add my code in comment on this site, so I had to answer my own question to insert the code. can you pls. tell me how I fix the getstring and getint error...thx!

Comment: You are using the C api, not the C++ api. You can get the data using row[0] and row[1] inside your while loop. That will give you pointers (null pointers in case of null values). You'll need to cast them. Here's the full documentation of the C api: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-functions.html

Comment: cool, thx...the row[0] worked for the key, but row[1] did not because it is a double value. I tried casting but obviously I was doing it wrong bcoz I got the following error:error: invalid cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘double’

Comment: I realized I have to use atof() to cast char* to double...it worked, thx for your help and the links :-)

Comment: Use atof(row[1]) to convert the string to a double.

Comment: alfonso, if I wanted to take the output from the SELECT statement and insert it into an instance of a class, how would I do that?